Regular horizontal strips on laptop screen under Ubuntu 22.04
Firstly, here is the configuration of my laptop:

type: HP Omen
Graphics card: Nvidia RTX 3080ti
OS: Ubuntu 22.04

The issue is that its screen suddenly has an issue some days ago: first it had some horizontal strips, which gradually covered the whole screen. Now it presents like this (e.g. the wallpaper).

The strips distribute very regularly, like every 3 or 4 pixels vertically. And they are actually not just black or colorful, rather similar with a drift of colors from other horizontal lines.
I have already reinstalled the latest Nvidia driver to 555.42.06, but the problem remains. What I really don't understand is that when I take a screenshot with this HP Omen laptop and open the screenshot with another device, such as my phone and another normal laptop, the screenshot looks totally fine.

Furthermore, I used this laptop to share the screen with zoom to another normal laptop, it turned out that on the other laptop, the screen is fine, without strips.
I consulted about this issue with HP technical support, but they only have troubleshooting steps for Windows and asked me to try to install Windows to see if it is possible to fix it, however the strips even start to appear during the installation and BIOS - boot options.


Is it still possible to fix through some methods of software? Or I could directly go to change another screen?

If I see something on a display but it doesn't appear on a screenshot, my first thought would be that there's something wrong with the display.

Do you mean it is physical damage of the screen? Is there possibility that nvidia-driver or kernel cause such problem? (by the way I forgot to mention, but this "drift" also happens during booting)

If you have more info for the question please edit the question and add it. Comments is not a good place for more info as they may not always be there and some people read the question and not the comments. As well please give an actual version number. You tag 22.04 but say it is Ubuntu Core 22. Only Core uses a single number as a version.

If it appears during BIOS/UEFI screens, this goes beyond Ubuntu and is probably issue with one of (1) your display, (2) your graphics card, or (3) the connection between them. Take it to a shop if you have one nearby that can check these, or open it up and check it yourself if you can.

I’m voting to close this question because it is a hardware issue.
